# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas but I have a problem I cannot wrap my head around.

I'm trying to add a new column to my `DataFrame`. To achieve that I use the `assign()` function.

Most of the examples on the internet are painfully trivial and I cannot find a solution for my problem.

What works:

```
my_dataset.assign(new_col=lambda x: my_custom_long_function(x['long_column']))

def my_custom_long_function(input)
  return input * 2
```

What doesn't work:

```
my_dataset.assign(new_col=lambda x: my_custom_string_function(x['string_column'])

def my_custom_string_function(input)
  return input.upper()
```

What confuses me is that in the debug I can see that even for `my_custom_long_function` the parameter is a `Series`, not a `long`.

I just want to use the `lambda` function and pass a **value of the column** to do my already written complicated functions. How do I do this?

Edit: The example here is just for demonstrative purpose, the real code is basically an existing complex function that does not care about panda's types and needs a `str` as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the column doesn't have a `upper` method, in order to use it, you need to do `str.upper`:

```
my_dataset.assign(new_col=lambda x: my_custom_string_function(x['string_column'])

def my_custom_string_function(input)
  return input.str.upper()
```

That said, I would use:

```
my_dataset['new column'] = my_dataset['string_column'].str.upper()
```

For efficiency.

**Edit:**

```
my_dataset['new column'] = my_dataset['string_column'].apply(lambda x: my_custom_string_function(x))
def my_custom_string_function(input):
    return input.upper()
```

Comment: I realised that, but the problem is that the function `my_custom_string_function` is a library function that does not care about panda's `Series`, it wants a `str`.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic I get it, but the best way would be the second example

Comment: I cannot use the second example, however you gave me an idea: `my_dataset.assign(new_col=lambda x: my_custom_string_function(x['string_column'].str)`. Now I get and error: TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not Series

Comment: The way I see it, think about not being able to change the signature or content of the `my_custom_string_function` and using it to add a new column named `new_col` by passing a value of existing column named `string_column`

Comment: Thank you. I needed multiple columns, but I got that working. If I use `apply` like you suggested, it works perfectly the way I expected it to work. For some reason the `assign` behaves differently. I'd love if you could explain why to me

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic `apply` does value by value.

Comment: Btw end solution was something like `my_dataset['new column'] = my_dataset.apply(lambda x:  my_custom_string_function(x['col1'], x['col2'], x['col3']))`